# Language-specific settings for SublimeREPL

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

How do I apply specific settings to new SublimeREPL buffers for specific languages?

Specifically, I want to have "Auto Wrap" set by default for the "REPL [fsharp]" buffers.